# Sharpening when editing RAW in CS6 from LR5

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

When opening a RAW file in Photoshop from LR5, will the standard +25 Sharpening be "remembered" in Photoshop, or will it be reset to zero?

Another question, not related to the previous one, is if there is in CS6 something similar to Copy and Paste of Development settings just like in LR.

Comment: These are two questions, could you please pose them separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few assumptions about your first question and did a quick test.

- I opened a DNG image in Lightroom 5 that I had never touched after import. It had the standard +25 sharpening applied to it automatically.
- I right clicked on the image, selected Edit In > Edit In Adobe Photoshop CS6.
- The image opened in Photoshop (not ACR).
- Looking at the two visually at 100%, they seem *perfectly identical*.

So, yes, it would seem Photoshop automatically applies the Lightroom standard sharpening.

Comment: Lightroom (and ACR, for that matter) actually sends Photoshop a TIFF created/developed from the RAW file (and linked to it, if opened as a Smart Object), not the RAW file itself. So yes, all development settings will be applied.